# How can I limit product categories to only three levels in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I dont want to limit just the display of categories in top navigation (maximal depth setting) but restrict user to creating categories upto a certain nesting level. Any solution programmatic or otherwise is appreciated.

Comment: I think you can play around app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Catalog : CategoryController.php

Comment: @gowri Changing the core is obviously a bad idea. How can I extend the controller, override changes and have Magento automatically pick up my version instead of the controller from the core?

Comment: @shaneep: you just copy CategoryController.php and create it in local as app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Catalog : CategoryController.php. That's it. we are overridden.

Answer (score 1):

This can be set in the back end.

system_config/edit/section/catalog/

Category Top Navigation

Maximum Depth

Job's a good 'un...

Comment: This only limits the nesting level displayed in the "top navigation bar", it doesn't restrict the admin from adding more nested levels (than the required limit)

Comment: Us designer/developer types fall into this mode of thinking where we think the user/admin is not to be trusted under any circumstances whatsoever. No wysiwyg entry - that has to be text only lest they put in blink, marquee and other tags outside of the signed off designs. Do I detect a case of this here? s for @gowri's suggestion - why not just copy the core to local for that controller and not-be-difficult-about-it?

Comment: Its a design requirement, we dont know the reason for its inclusion and initiating the process to change the specs for such a little change is way too much trouble.

Comment: Big up front designs - I love em. You could write a module that has an Observer that listens to adminhtml_catalog_category_tree_can_add_sub_category and returns an admin message if the category depth is greater than three. Or just not deliver on that part of the 'design'.

Comment: ...or for extreme laziness edit the admin template and put a big box at the top saying 'Remember: category depth cannot be greater than 3!!!'